# Upload folder is not writable, even when permissions are correct

Tags: uploads

I recent migrated my site from Godaddy to Webfaction. On migration, I get this error:

> Upload folder is not writable. Export and file upload features will
>   not be functional.

Naturally, I check the permissions of the folder - and they are correct. Just to be safe, I changed it recursively to "777" (as a test, not permanently), and I still cannot upload images.

How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: I had to run `stat -c %a /apps/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/` and then `chmod -R 775 /apps/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/`

Comment: Very simple, go to youe WB dashboard sitting - media - past the defult (wp-content/uploads) then press SAVE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a server permission problem. According to the WP docs:

> Any file that needs write access from WordPress should be owned or
>   group-owned by the user account used by the WordPress (which may be
>   different than the server account). For example, you may have a user
>   account that lets you FTP files back and forth to your server, but
>   your server itself may run using a separate user, in a separate
>   usergroup, such as dhapache or nobody. If WordPress is running as the
>   FTP account, that account needs to have write access, i.e., be the
>   owner of the files, or belong to a group that has write access. In the
>   latter case, that would mean permissions are set more permissively
>   than default (for example, 775 rather than 755 for folders, and 664
>   instead of 644).

From http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

> How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Ask Webfaction. Sounds like they need to give you the ability to chmod files/folders or they need to do it for you.

*And, FYI, search first for a common issue like permissions; there are many answers already on WP Dev.*

Comment: Thanks, now that you mention it, it may be a groups issue.

Comment: I reached out to web faction and they have no clue either. I do sysadmin work for several websites, hosting load balanced WordPress instances, this isn't simply a permissions/groups issue. Any other ideas as to what I can do @songdogtech

Answer (score 5):

> Upload folder is not writable. Export and file upload features will not be functional.

This specific error string comes from Gravity Forms and not WordPress itself.

Go to Settings → Media and check the value for "Store uploads in this folder" is correct. Using the default of `wp-content/uploads` will remove the error as long as that directory has the correct permissions set.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by doing following:

Open myphpadmin through your cpanel and open your database.

Select option table

Find row of named as upload_path and click edit

Delete the value and hit save

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WordPress multisite, I found this to be the solution.

WordPress multisite's "Upload Path" should be set to a server-relative path (e.g. `/home/serveraccountname/public_html/wp-content/uploads`).

The "Upload URL Path" should be the URI (e.g. `http://example.com/wp-content/uploads`).

Ignore the `/sites/1/` fragment for sub-sites - WordPress will add these automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This may work for certain scenarios. The error does occur if you have exceeded your space limit with your host provider

Answer (score 0):

I had also migrated a WordPress site, and encountered this same problem.

After much digging, I realised that the hosting account name had changed
As the Wordpress upload path includes the hosting account folder this needs to be edited

Wordpress stores the upload path in the wp_options table in "upload_path"
/home/**hosting account name**/public_html/wp-content/uploads

Edit the field with phpMyAdmin and all fixed ;)

Hope this helps you

Pete Cornish

Answer (score 0):

Changing the url on the WP settings > Media link will correct this. Go to the section "Store uploads in this folder", and ensure the url matches the correct location of your uploads folder.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to add the mod_suexec apache module

Comment: That means your WordPress files are owned by someone other than the main web server user?